# CNN sharing weights in feature map

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, weight-initialization

what do they mean when they say all
neurons in a channel share weights with one another? Do they mean that in a chanel or a featue map the weights are the same ?

Comment: What i undertstood is that each neuron in a single feature map uses the same filter or kernel ?

Comment: Please see my drawings [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271198/convolution-operator-in-cnn-and-how-it-differs-from-feed-forward-nn-operation/409172#409172), and consider what a fully-connected layer would look like.